# Buttons Missing in Firefox Bootstrap 3 Modals

Tags: css, firefox, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I can't figure out why my buttons aren't displaying correctly in Firefox. Work fine in Chrome and Internet Explorer. You can view my problem here: test.loginsm.com

The "Social" buttons aren't being displayed when clicking on "Sign in" and "Register".

This problem is specific to being displayed in Modals.

Bootply (more or less): http://www.bootply.com/private/kNg8uRQkQ1#

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Using Firefox 30.0, I'm not seeing the problem you describe. What version of Firefox are you using?

Comment: Weird, Firefox 31.0 and Firefox Aurora (33.0a2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem thanks to Serlite getting the gears turning in my head.

Turns out it was an add on, Specifically a Social Button remover. It didn't seem to like Facebook or Twitter but preferred Google+! Just disabled it and my buttons showed up!

Thanks!

Comment: Please Accept your answer, So that no one tries to reinvent the wheel!!

Comment: 12 hours to go before it will let me.

Answer (score 0):

$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout "close,minimize,maximize:"